# Variadic Template Specialization Overload works in GCC but not MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have the following function declarations

```
    template<typename RET, typename... PARAMS>
    RET Execute(PARAMS... params)
    { ... }
    
    template<typename RET>
    RET Execute()
    { ... }

    template<typename... PARAMS>
    void Execute(PARAMS... params)
    { ... }

    void Execute();
```

These calls work fine in both GCC and MSVC

```
    Execute<int32_t>(static_cast<int8_t>(0), static_cast<int32_t>(0))
    Execute<int32_t>()
    Execute(static_cast<uint8_t>(0))
    Execute()
```

This call works fine in GCC, but not in MSVC. I get an error for an ambiguous call to overload function. Just because the return type is the same as the first parameter.

```
    Execute<int32_t>(static_cast<int32_t>(0), static_cast<int32_t>(0))
```

Considering it is not possible to explicitly give the typenames of the parameter pack, it is not ambiguous. Why does MSVC seem to have this wrong? Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: I have expected ambiguous call for all clang/gcc/msvc [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6GPa59P4v)

Comment: *"Considering it is not possible to explicitly give the typenames of the parameter pack"*. You can provide explicitly typename for ("beginning" of) parameter packs.

Comment: Apparently you can explicitly give the typenames of the parameter pack. Something with the way it was all written inline on my ASSERT test function was causing a syntax error when adding the parameter pack typenames. i tried it on a seperate line with the resulting value being placed in a variable and it worked just fine. Thank you! if you want to create an answer i will accept it.

Comment: You might also select overload with casting `static_cast<int32_t (*)(int32_t, int32_t)>(&Execute)(0, 0);` (unambiguous, deduction happens), `static_cast<void (*)(int32_t, int32_t)>(Execute<int32_t, int32_t>)(0, 0);` (ambiguous, you have to provide first parameters) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hq7a64sGc).

Comment: That is an interesting way to do it, but would kind of defeat the purpose of using the overload in the first place (Readability). At that point i would just give the functions different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This call works fine in GCC, but not in MSVC.

In my Debian stable, I get the same error also with clang++ 11.0.1-2 ("error: call to 'Execute' is ambiguous") and g++ 10.2.1 (" error: call of overloaded ‘Execute<int32_t>(int32_t, int32_t)’ is ambiguous").

> Considering it is not possible to explicitly give the typenames of the parameter pack

Not exactly: you can explicit the typenames of the arguments or the types of the first arguments; this permit to overrides the typenames deduction from the arguments.

> Why does MSVC seem to have this wrong?

My question is: why your g++ seems to have this right?

> Is there anyway to fix this?

Yes, a very simple way: add a variadic list of non-types template parameter before the variadic list of the argument types.

I mean, write the third `Execute()` as follows

```
template <int..., typename... PARAMS>
void Execute (PARAMS... params)
{ /* ... */ }
```

and maybe also the first one as follows

```
template <typename RET, int..., typename... PARAMS>
RET Execute (PARAMS... params)
{ /* ... */ }
```

This way you impose the `PARAMS` types deduction from the `params` and a explicit template parameter is necessarily the return type (when you can express it).

Comment: GCC 9.3 did not complain. Your solution works perfectly! Thank you!